# Gitで行が削除されたコミット番号を知る方法

Tags: git

Gitであるファイルから1行削除されていることは認識できたのですが、該当行がどのコミットで消えたのか知るコマンドはありますか？　コミットをバイナリーサーチで目Grepしていけばいづれたどりつけるのですが....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git log`の`-S<string>`オプションでいかがでしょうか。

> -S<string>
>              Look for differences that change the number of occurrences of the specified string (i.e.
>              addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter's use.
>             It is useful when you're looking for an exact block of code (like a struct), and want to know
>              the history of that block since it first came into being: use the feature iteratively to feed
>              the interesting block in the preimage back into -S, and keep going until you get the very
>              first version of the block.

`git log -p -S'削除された文字列' ファイルパス` というようなコマンドで所望の動作となるかと思います。

Answer (score 6):

参考までに、 `git blame --reverse` を用いると、「特定のリビジョンのファイルに対して、それぞれの行がどのリビジョンまで存在していたか」を取得できます。

```
git blame --reverse START..END file-to-blame
```

(正確には、上の例においては、START リビジョンにおける `file-to-blame` のそれぞれの行に対して、指定されたリビジョン範囲の中で、最後にその行が存在していたリビジョンを blame で求めることができます。)